# Relative Version in Maven Sub-modules?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a parent pom as a module(let's call it `parent-module`), and I have several child modules(let them be `child-1`, `child-2`, `child-3`).

Now in the pom file of the `parent-module`, I defines the parent's version as: `1.0.12`. In the child module, I'll have to refer to the parent pom in this way:

```
child-1 --> parent/version: 1.0.12
child-2 --> parent/version: 1.0.12
child-3 --> parent/version: 1.0.12
```

Now say I want to upgrade the version to `1.0.13`, I'll have to change the parent version to `1.0.13` first, and then change each of the reference in the children version to the parent module module to `1.0.13`.

That is, in order to change a single number, I'll have to manually change 4 pom files.

I want to ask if there's a clever way to configure the pom file, so that I can have a single source of truth for the module value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hierarchy of maven projects without scattering the version number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415764/hierarchy-of-maven-projects-without-scattering-the-version-number)

Comment: See http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/.

Comment: or see https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin