# (MAVEN) Avoid hardcoding parent pom version

Tags: maven, parent-pom

I need to build a pom with different pom parent's versions. For doing that I want to resolve the parent version with a variable.

Is there a way for the version referring to the parent pom in a child pom to be a variable?

Comment: Why do you need different parent versions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hierarchy of maven projects without scattering the version number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415764/hierarchy-of-maven-projects-without-scattering-the-version-number)

Comment: This duplicate candidate is a poor choice given that it references Maven 2 which has significant behavioural differences to the current Maven 3.x releases.